# Фласк не видит темплейт (TemplateNotFound), хотя он лежит в нужной папке

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

Есть кусок кода на python flask, который должен добавлять новую запись в бд. (реализация кривая, делалось на скорую руку). Собственно набросал форму для добавления на сайт, в папке tempates присутствует addbook.html, форма отображалась корректно, однако после прописывания функционала в routes.py стала падать с ошибкой. Собственно хочу узнать причину (помимо криворукости) и как исправить.

```
@app.route('/personal', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #панель админа для добавления книг
def personal():
    form = addBookForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if current_user.isadmin:
            return render_template(url_for('addbook'))
        else:
            return render_template(url_for('error'))
    else:
            render_template(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/addbook') 
def addbook():
    form = addBookForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if current_user.isadmin:
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                book = Book(isbn = form.isbn.data, cost = form.cost.data, creationYear = form.creationYear.data,storage = form.storage.data,title = form.title.data,author = form.author.data, publick = form.publick.data, about = form.about.data, genre = form.genre.data)
                conn = connectDB.get_connection()
                curs = conn.cursor() #опечатки которые мне лень везде править creationYear - year, publick - public
                sql = "INSERT INTO books(isbn, cost, year, storage, title, author, public, about, genre) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                curs.execute(sql, (book.isbn, book.cost, book.creationYear, book.storage, book.title, book.author, book.publick, book.about, book.genre))
                conn.commit()
                curs.close()
                conn.close()
                flash('Книга успешно добавлена!')
        else: 
            return (url_for('error'))
    else: 
            return (url_for('error'))
    return render_template("addbook.html", title='title', form=form)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "W:\Позимствованно с GiThub\project2020\app\routes.py", line 141, in personal
    return render_template(url_for('map'))
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:/addbook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причиной ошибки было использование render_template, тут нужно использовать redirect

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема решается добавлением простого конфига например таким образом

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="jinja_templates")
```

Либо если проблема возникла на сервере, то перенесите папку с шаблонами в корень или в каталог уровнем выше, чем тот в которым лежит .py файл

Comment: добавил. Теперь возникает: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: попробуй удалить фласк и ещё раз установить